# Solving $x''(t)=2x(t)^3$ with $x(0)=x(1)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, euler-lagrange-equation

I have to find the minimum of the functional

$$
J(x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \left(x'(t) +x^2(t) \right)^2\, dt
$$

I have calculated the Euler-Lagrange equation, but I can't solve the corresponding differential equation:
$$x''(t)=2x(t)^3$$
with the conditions $x(0)=x(1)=0$.

Can someone explain me please how to solve it?

Comment: Multiply your ODE by $x'$ and integrate to get $$\frac{1}{2} x'^{2} = \frac{1}{2} x^{4} + C_{1}$$ which is then separable.

Comment: @mattos I already have found this result, but then I can't solve the equation because of the term x'^2..Can you write down the passages to find the result?

Comment: Are you sure the initial conditions are right?

Comment: @Raffaele yes I'm sure that the conditions are right!!

Comment: Well, since $J(x)\ge0$ for all $x$, and $J(x)=0$ for $x\equiv0$, which also happens to satisfy the conditions $x(0)=x(1)=0$, you don't need sophisticated machinery to find the minimum.

Comment: With these conditions I don't get any solution with *Wolfram Mathematica*, while the general solution is in term of Jacobi elliptic function  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%5Bt%5D+%3D%3D+2+x%5Bt%5D%5E3

Comment: I agree with @ProfessorVector. In my opinion the minimum is for $x(t)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand function is
$$f(x,x',t)=\left(x'(t) +x^2(t) \right)^2$$
Euler-Lagrange equation
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}-{\frac {\operatorname {d} }{\operatorname {d} t}}\left({\frac {\partial f}{\partial {x'}}}\right)=0$$
leads to the ODE
$$4 x(t) \left(x'(t)+x(t)^2\right)-2 \left(x''(t)+2 x(t) x'(t)\right)=0$$
expanding and simplifying
$$2 x(t)^3-x''(t)=0;\;x(0)=x(1)=0$$

the unique function which satisfies the DE and the initial conditions is $x(t)=0$.

Comment: Thanks!I have another question: I know that if (,′,)=(′()+2())2 is convex then x(t)=0 is also the minimum of J. Is the function f convex? How can I prove it?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=2x^3 \implies 2\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=4x^3 \frac{dx}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left ( \frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 =2x^3 \frac{dx}{dt}.$$
Integrating w.r.t. $t$, we get
$$\int \frac{d}{dt}\left ( \frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 dt =\int 4 x^3 dx \implies  \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 = x^4+A \implies \frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{x^4+A}$$
$$\implies \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^4+A}}=\int dt +B=t+B.$$

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a+x^4}} \, dx$ gives an elliptic function of the first kind